# Como utilizar várias respostas para a mesmo variável em apenas um if?

Tags: javascript, if, else

É possível utilizar apenas um `if` para vários possíveis valores da mesma variável?
Por exemplo:

Em vez de escrever:

```
var nome=""
var nome=prompt("Digite seu nome");

if (nome === null){
  alert(Você clicou em cancelar);
}

if (nome === ""){
  (seu nome não foi informado);
}
```

Ou seja, algum separador que me permita utilizar apenas um `if` para esses 2 possíveis valores de `if` informados dentro da *prompt box*.

Comment: Você conhece o básico de lógica de programação? Pesquise sobre operadores lógicos.

Comment: Guilherme, você conhece operadores lógicos? Dê uma olhada: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operadores_Logicos

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 3):

Não é possível, se você tem duas condições completamente diferente e ações distintas a serem realizadas você terá que fazê-los separadamente, é uma questão de lógica e matemática.

Não adianta usar operador lógico porque as condições não podem ser agrupadas, haverá dois `if`. Você pode até user o operador condicional para evitar o `if`, mas não para evitar duas condições que é na verdade o que gostaria.

Então usar o operador condicional apenas deixará o código mais ilegível sem fazer o que deseja.

Seria bem útil mudar a lógica porque se cair em um `if` não faz sentido fazer o outro, então o seu código sem erros de sintaxe e sem redundância e com um pouco mais de sentido fazendo algo:

```js
var nome = prompt("Digite seu nome");
if (nome === null) alert("Você clicou em cancelar");
else if (nome === "") alert("Seu nome não foi informado");
else alert(nome);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/TwoIf.js).

Tem um jeito que eu acho mais simples, ainda que quem não tem experiência pode achar mais complicado por parecer mais longo (*early exit* torna o fluxo mais fácil de entender), e ele só pode ser aplicado em uma função, o que é o caso sempre em códigos reais, ou seja, assim aprende fazer o jeito mais correto (na verdade em código real é tudo feito de forma diferente disso):

```js
function pegaNome() {
    var nome = prompt("Digite seu nome");
    if (nome === null) {
        alert("Você clicou em cancelar");
        return;
    }
    if (nome === "") {
        alert("Seu nome não foi informado");
        return;
    }
    alert(nome);
}
pegaNome();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/EarlyExit.js).

Se for usar o operador condicional faça assim para ficar um pouco mais legível (note que se não gera um valor no final para usar em outro expressão ou para guardar em variável é abuso do operador, ainda que possa ser usado), quem não tem experiência não percebe como isso pode ajudar evitar confusões no código, mas quem é experiente mesmo prefere o `if`:

```js
var nome = prompt("Digite seu nome");
(nome === null)
    ? alert("Você clicou em cancelar")
    : (nome === "")
        ? alert("Seu nome não foi informado")
        : alert(nome);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/NestedConditional.js).

Ainda é esquisito e se você mistura linhas sem `;` onde precisa aí pode dar muito errado, por isso eu sempre falo para usar `;` onde é necessário mesmo que a linguagem não deixe, isso evitará ter que fazer código ilegível para funcionar além de evitar erros em *corner cases*. Mas ultimamente percebemos pelas perguntas aqui que as pessoas andam seguindo "cursos" que ensinam más práticas.

Comment: Eita, respondeu duas perguntas minhas de uma vez !

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar um operador condicional ternário para atingir o resultado desejado (embora não ache que seja o mais legível):

```
nome === null ? alert('Você clicou em cancelar') : (nome ===  ? alert('seu nome não foi informado') : false);
```

---

> [**Operador Condicional Ternário**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operador_Condicional)
>
> O operador condicional (ternário) é o único operador JavaScript que possui três operandos. Este operador é frequentemente usado como um atalho para a instrução if.